# Memory leaks without allocating any memory

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I was just testing out some c code I was writing and I found that I had a lot of memory leaks, so I wanted to see where they were coming from. All the code I had was:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Just a simple main that did nothing and I had all these memory leaks:

```
==38882== HEAP SUMMARY:
==38882==     in use at exit: 58,678 bytes in 363 blocks
==38882==   total heap usage: 514 allocs, 151 frees, 62,544 bytes allocated
==38882== 
==38882== LEAK SUMMARY:
==38882==    definitely lost: 8,624 bytes in 14 blocks
==38882==    indirectly lost: 1,168 bytes in 5 blocks
==38882==      possibly lost: 4,925 bytes in 68 blocks
==38882==    still reachable: 43,961 bytes in 276 blocks
==38882==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==38882== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==38882== 
==38882== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==38882== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

When I run this code on my university's computers I have no memory leaks. Is there something on my local machine that is causing this many memory leaks?

Comment: What's the setup you're using? OS? compiler?

Comment: I am using a mac running mountain lion. I am compiling with gcc.

Comment: @KatieCalabro Valgrind on OS X and especially on Mountain Lion is **very buggy.** You are most likely getting false positives.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine. Your program uses runtime library (i.e. `libc` or equivalent) and the library allocates some memory for own needs.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error on my Mac. It's either a valgrind problem or (more likely) a library problem on the Mac. I would suggest to use valgrind only on Linux.